# Wordpress array_column not working on wp_get_post_terms

Tags: php, wordpress, array-map, array-column

I am trying to extract an array of term_ids from wp_get_post_terms using array_column, but it doesn't return anything.

Here is the code:

```
$atype = wp_get_post_terms($property_ID, 'property_category', true);
$types = array_column($atype, 'term_id'); // Not working so using array map
$types2 = array_map(function($te) {
  return $te->term_id;
}, $atype);

echo '$atype: ';
echo '<pre>'; print_r($atype); echo '</pre>';
echo '$types: ';
echo '<pre>'; print_r($types); echo '</pre>';
echo '$types2: ';
echo '<pre>'; print_r($types2); echo '</pre>';
```

Here is the result:

```
$atype: Array
(
    [0] => WP_Term Object
    (
        [term_id] => 51
        [name] => Office
        [slug] => office
        [term_group] => 0
        [term_taxonomy_id] => 51
        [taxonomy] => property_category
        [description] => 
        [parent] => 0
        [count] => 1
        [filter] => raw
    )

)
$types: Array
(
)
$types2: Array
(
    [0] => 51
)
```

Why isn't array_column working?  Based on docs, it should.  I am using > php 5.5.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

Answer (score 4):

That's because `wp_get_post_terms` return and array of *object*s, not a 2-dimensional array. `array_column` only works on 2-dimensional arrays before php 7.0.0.